# Split the cell into two using pdf itext

Tags: java, itext

I have a pdf table generated using java(itext). In this I have a column named 'Tax'. Now I want to split this column to 2 i.e

This is the current tax field:

```
|----------|
| Tax      |
|----------|
|          |
|          |
|----------|
```

I want to split this as defined below:

```
|----------|
|   Tax    |
|----------|
|Name|  %  |
|----|---- |
|    |     |
|    |     | 
|    |     |
|----------|
```

Please help me.

Comment: Use two columns to start with and use `colspan` in the first header line.

Comment: @mkl It would be helpful if you can just explain. I am new to java and itext.

Comment: Cf. Joris' answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(getOutputFile()));
Document layoutDocument = new Document(pdfDocument);

// build table
Table table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[]{0.5f, 0.5f}));

// add "Tax" header
Cell headerCell = new Cell(1,2);      // rowspan = 1, colspan = 2
headerCell.add(new Paragraph("Tax"));
table.addCell(headerCell);

// add "Name" and "%" header
table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Name")));
table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("%")));

// add arbitrary data
table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("The java cookbook")));
table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("6")));

layoutDocument.add(table);
layoutDocument.close();
```

For more information on using iText to generate tables, there's a complete tutorial over on http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/itext-7-tables